# bash: send a control signal to a while loop?

Tags: bash

Simple bash line:

```
for h in $(cat /tmp/hosts); do ssh $h; done
```

If I type Ctrl-C it exits the `for` loop, as expected. But I'd like a way to send a signal that will break from the current ssh line only, and proceed to the next iteration in the loop. This would be useful in situations where I don't want to or can't log into a particular host, but I want to proceed immediately with others in the file. Is there a way to designate a control character that can be trapped in this manner?

ANSWER:
I figured it out.

```
for h in $(cat /tmp/hosts); do trap 'continue' 3; ssh $h; done
```

Signal 3 corresponds to `Ctrl-\` . So, to kill the current ssh command (before you've logged into the host, it won't work if you've already logged in) and move to the next one in the loop, type `Ctrl-\` . To terminate the whole "script" type `Ctrl-C`. Effective; clean; does exactly what I need.

Comment: I agree with kasperd, this is not a good direction to take your design. This was working as intended; your `ctrl-c` was being sent to the remote shell because you were running `ssh` interactively. By "fixing" this with a trap, you have removed the ability to send the interrupt signal to the remote shell. This can not only have unintended consequences, but it also violates the design principle of [least surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). If you have other members on your team who might use this script, *please* do not use this approach.

Comment: *s/interrupt/quit/* on my comment, but the opinion remains unchanged. Stealing signals from an interactive shell is A Bad Thing in this industry. This strategy is acceptable in a hobbyist context, but we have a different audience here.

Comment: There's no reason to re-execute `trap` on every iteration of the loop. Use `while read -r varname` instead of `for` to iterate over the contents of a file. Get in the habit of always quoting variables when they're expanded.

Comment: Add en extra field in `/tmp/hosts`, 0=notSeen,1=current,2=done. Your script searches for a host with status current, asks for retry and continues with notSeen hosts. When you interrupt your ssh, you can restart your script that will take the next host automaticly.

Comment: Comment context: this post was originally on ServerFault.

Comment: I don't know what the big fuss is here. I've got a file of hostnames, most of which I want to ssh into one-at-a-time and run some commands, but some I want to skip over (I won't know which ones until I issue the ssh command). The solution I give lets me do this without any problems. When I'm logged into a host, Ctrl-c works in that ssh sessions as expected. When I'm not logged into a host, I can skip a host with Ctrl-\ and I can terminate the whole script with Ctrl-C, just as expected. There aren't any issues with tty's or anything else. The for loop + trap works perfectly.

Comment: Your question was migrated to a site where it doesn't matter anymore. Let it go.

Comment: @AndrewB: what matters is accuracy

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking should be happening by default when pressing ctrl+c. However I spot a few mistakes in your command.

First of all, both the `while` loop and the `ssh` command are reading from the same pipe. This can lead to unexpected results as the first `ssh` command reads all the hostnames, and the `while` command will see `EOF`, when it should have found more hostnames.

The usual solution to that problem is to use the `-n` flag for the `ssh` command.

Moreover running `ssh` without a command while `stdin` is not a tty cannot be recommended. I guess you really wanted to add a command for the remote system in that `ssh` command.

This is how the command could look:

`while read h; do ssh -n "$h" 'sleep 10'; done </tmp/hosts`

Other than pressing ctrl-c you can alternatively kill the `ssh` command from a different shell. In a different shell you can type `ps -fC ssh` to get a list of running `ssh` processes and you can kill one of them using `kill` followed by the pid.

Comment: I tested the command which I typed above, and pressing ctrl-c only terminates the current `ssh` command. But it only works if I press ctrl-c while the `sleep` command is running. I can hit a spot while `ssh` is logging in, where pressing ctrl-c stops the entire sequence. Also if the input file is so long that the `cat` command could be killed before completing, there could be a problem. I'll change the command to fix that.

Comment: No. {Ctrl-c} just kills the whole loop.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the strategy you're looking for, but there are a few alternatives that do not involve stealing signals from an interactive shell:

- `ssh` has a "terminate" escape sequence that is intended for this purpose. Type the following keys immediately after pressing enter (but only on a session you're ready to lose): `~.` Keep in mind that this kills the topmost of your nested `ssh` commands; this more effective for remote hosts if your initial connection is not via the `ssh` command. (as your comment and downvote suggests, you are nesting)
- `Ctrl-D` on an empty prompt is a graceful shell hangup. Saves you the trouble of typing `exit` or `logout`, and is kind enough to advise you of running programs in the background. If you *really* need to break out of `ssh` though, stick with `~.`.

Comment: {~.} kills my tmux session.

Comment: @Michael Because you're nesting multiple ssh commands and not disclosing that.

Comment: not nesting anything. each ssh is executed independently. what is it you don't understand about that?

Comment: `~.` (no meta characters) will terminate the first invocation of a `ssh` command that reads the characters interactively. That's it. If something is unexpectedly dying, it's on the other side of a `ssh` command, or the sequence is not being used in a context I'm describing.

Comment: it kills my tmux session and the shell that invoked it. It doesn't affect the for loop or the ssh prompt.

Comment: I use `tmux` and `bash` religiously. Under normal circumstances, the only command that character sequence is meaningful to is `ssh`. Beyond that I cannot tell you what is going on.

Comment: I don't know either. If I figure out I'll update here.